# Getting table/view not found when using dbms_resource_manager within a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm able to run an anonymous PL/SQL block and set an initial_rsrc_consumer_group via DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER in Oracle 19; however, when I attempt to name it as a stored procedure it throws ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

Anonymous plsql block that runs ok:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_resource_manager_privs.grant_switch_consumer_group('TESTUSR', 'TEST_GROUP', false);
  3    dbms_resource_manager.create_pending_area();
  4    dbms_resource_manager.set_initial_consumer_group('TESTUSER', 'TEST_GROUP');
  5    dbms_resource_manager.validate_pending_area();
  6    dbms_resource_manager.submit_pending_area();
  7    dbms_resource_manager.clear_pending_area();
  8  end;
  9  
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

The definition of the procedure is below

```
create or replace procedure jomccr.set_consumer_group (
  p_username dba_users.username%type 
) is
begin
  dbms_resource_manager_privs.grant_switch_consumer_group(upper(p_username), 'TEST_GROUP', false); 
  dbms_resource_manager.create_pending_area();
  dbms_resource_manager.set_initial_consumer_group(upper(p_username), 'TEST_GROUP');
  dbms_resource_manager.validate_pending_area();
  dbms_resource_manager.submit_pending_area();
  dbms_resource_manager.clear_pending_area();
end ;
```

Whenever I execute it, I receive the following error:

```
SQL> execute jomccr.set_consumer_group('TESTUSR')

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_RMIN", line 36
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_RMIN", line 85
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER_PRIVS", line 96
ORA-06512: at "JOMCCR.SET_CONSUMER_GROUP", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

What changed now that I've named the procedure?

Comment: The Grants. As an anonymous block it runs under grants that you have, which you may have gotten from a role grant. However, as  Procedure the owner (in this case you) must have a direct grant.

Comment: Thanks, I have access to a more privileged "administrator" account that I was using to run the tests, but I was building the procedure in my own schema. To fix I ended up building the procedure in the new "administrator" schema and it runs fine.

I assumed a procedure was executed with the privileges of the caller but that is not the case.

Comment: Glad it's working for you. If you want to run under caller privileges you need to specify **authid current user** in the package, procedure, function, type header. The alternative is **authid definer**. If not specified the default in authid definer. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809).